# launcher properties / display

Tags: launcher

I wish that the launcher has some properties which we can access / change with right click (like in windows). Also, the launcher location at the left side keeps bothering me and would prefer to have it at the bottom. Is there a solution for both? I use ubuntu 12.04 and am pretty new to linux and would prefer if I don't have to run commands from the terminal and could do this with a nice GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a good way to switch the launcher to the bottom using Unity (I wanted that until I got used to it I loved it). But you can hide the launcher and install a program like Docky (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/docky/) which looks a whole lot like the Apple Dock. I have also included another method (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/tweak-ubuntu-unity-get-a-dock-style-launcher-and-unity-dash/) Hope it helps.